# How does the .NET CLR work?

Tags: asp.net, clr

I've been searching this on net, but could not find one in layman's language. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Layman's description, I would go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime

That's about as simple as it can be explained in Layman's terms, with plenty of links defining terms a layman may not be familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best definition is in CLR via C#, though to class that as a book describing things in Layman's terms would just be wrong! However, the [Wikipedia definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) seems simple enough to understand.

Comment: I've translated the CLR via CSharp, 3rd Ed to Persian language, I strongly recommend you to read that in depth to know what's behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this a useful introduction from TheServerSide
[link text](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=DM_CLR)